# programmatically get IDs of list from urls

Tags: list, spweb, sputility

Is it possible to retrieve the ID of a list or library with a url?

For example, http://MyPortal/MySubsite/MyDocuments/Forms/AllItems.aspx

If so, please provide me with some sample code.

Many thanks,

KS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint is extremely large about the Url we pass it so even though the url isn't really to the site or to the list (but to a view) both constructor for SPSite and SPWeb.GetList accepts it:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(url))
  using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    var list = web.GetList(url);
    // ID is now in list.ID;
  }
```